# Rails, drop down list for increase items quantity in the cart

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a beginner in ROR, and I' m building an online shop, and I'm trying to do a drop down list to increase quantity of products to add in the cart at the same time.
I did a form for, linked with the controller, but I don't know why it do not work at all, It shows the form, but It always add elements one by one to the cart. I can choose a quantity in my list, But it is not recognized and add one element when I click on the "add" button

Here is my shop view :

```html
<div class="popup-price-and-add">
  <span class="popup-price"><%=number_to_currency(product.price)%></span><br/>
  <%= text_field_tag 'quantity' %>
  <%= form_for(line_items_path(:set_quantity)) do |form|%>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :quantity%>
    <%= form.select :quantity, (1..10) %>
   <p>
     <% end %>
     <%= link_to image_tag("/elem/Btn-add.png", :class =>"popup-add"), line_items_path(product_id: product), remote: true, :method => :post, :class => "popup-add" %>
 </div>
```

and here is my line_items_controller:

```html
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create, :destroy]
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    session[:counter] = 0
    quantity = params[:quantity]
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      if current_cart.line_items.empty?
        format.html{redirect_to(store_url, :notice=>'Your cart is empty')}
      else
      format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart, :notice=> 'Item has been removed from your cart.') }
    end
      format.xml { head :ok}
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id)
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:quantity)
    end
end
```

as you see, in my create method, I defined a quantity and I permitted it with :  params.require(:line_item).permit(:quantity).

Hope It will help you to help me!
Thanks.

Comment: When you say " I don't know why it do not work at all" can you elaborate on what the current behavior is?

Comment: Yes for sure. It always add elements one by one. I can choose a quantity in my list, But it is not recognized and add one element when I click on the "add" button

Comment: Your Ajax code just executes when the added line items are saved but you don't have a submit button for your form, so it never saves itself. For this kind of stuff it's better to use jQuery. (it will be easier for you and for anyone who gets to read the code after you)

Comment: Ok I understand but could you explain what I should do please?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a database table for the Items with a column of quantity but if you already have a Items model but without the quantity value you can do this

`rails g migration AddQuantityToItems quantity:integer`

```
Rake db:migrate
```

then you need to do something like this in the view:

```
<%= form_for(Item) do  |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :quantity, class: 'cart_quantity' %>
 <p class="cart_quantity"></p>
 <button class='quantity_down'></button>
 <button class='quantity_up'></button>
 <%= f.submit 'Add to cart' %>
<% end %>
```

jQuery

```
 var quantity = 0;
 $(document).on('click', 'quantity_down', function() {
   quantity -= 1
   $('cart_quantity').text(quantity);
   $('cart_quantity').val(quantity);
 });

 $(document).on('click', 'quantity_up', function() {
  quantity += 1;
  $('cart_quantity').text(quantity);
  $('cart_quantity').val(quantity);
 });
```

If you really specifically need a drop down list, thats also possible just switch the buttons with a select dropdown and change the jQuery accordingly.

This is just to give you an idea, i don't know your code so you have to work around this.

Comment: this never worked for me.. this search for some routes that do not exist..

Comment: It's because this isn't the exact answer, i can't even see all the necessary code in your post so i can't give an accurate answer. But this is how it should work for you. You just have to work around the <%= form_for(item) do |f| %> etc.. since i made that up

Comment: what part of my code do you need to give me a more accurate answer? I'm a beginner in RoR and this a part that blocks me much, That would be great if you could help me more with that.. :)